# PHP: How to find a value from an array in another array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have a main array, Array X

```
[
{'id': 3, 'name':'A'},
{'id': 5, 'name':'B'}
]
```

At the same time, I have another array, array Y: [3,5,12]

My goal is to check if any value from array Y exists as id in any object in Array X. Even if there is one match, I want to return True.

I tried array_search() and array_in() but I'm not sure how to write the logic.

Any help is appreciated. This is in PHP

Comment: you had tried anything ?

Comment: is the content in your main array an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy to understand solution.
- First correct the format of json structure.
- Loop through your `$x` array and on each iteration check that the value of `id` found in `$y` array.

```
$x = json_decode('[{"id": 3, "name":"A"},{"id": 5, "name":"B"}]', TRUE);
$y = [3,5,12];
$search = search($x, $y);
echo $search;
function search($x, $y) {
    foreach($x as $val){
      if (in_array($val['id'], $y))
          return "exists";
    }
    return "not exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is not a valid JSON.
    [
      {'id': 3, 'name':'A'},
      {'id': 5, 'name':'B'}
    ]

Correct json would be like this :

```
[{"id": 3,"name": "A"},{"id": 5,"name": "B"}]
```

So you have do something like this

```
function findInJson($searchArray){
    $jsonString = '[{"id": 3,"name": "A"},{"id": 5,"name": "B"}]';
    $jsonArray  = json_decode($jsonString, true); // Incase you want to user your own array you can use it here
    $keys       = array_column($jsonArray, 'id');
    return (count(array_intersect($keys, $searchArray)) !== 0);

}
// Call like this
$common = findInJson([3,5,12]);

var_dump($common);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Note that I'm assuming a PHP array rather than a JSON object as input. Time complexity is O(n^2).

```
$x = [
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'A'],
  ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'B']
];
$y = [3, 5, 12];
$z = [1, 14, 13];

function any_in_arr($needle_arr, $haystack, $field) {
  foreach ($haystack as $h) {
    foreach ($needle_arr as $n) {
      if ($h[$field] === $n) { return true; }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

var_dump(any_in_arr($y, $x, 'id')); // true
var_dump(any_in_arr($z, $x, 'id')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with array functions only and without a loop.

```
$x = json_decode('[{"id": 3, "name":"A"},{"id": 5, "name":"B"}]', true);
$x = array_column($x,'name','id');
$y = [3,5,12];
$y = array_flip($y);    
$res = array_intersect_key($x, $y);    
echo empty($res) ? 'not exist' : 'exist';
```